# Soft Touch Lamp Turning on by Itself

Tags: switches, lighting

[image]This has been driving me crazy for several years now -- my soft touch lamp has been turning itself on most mornings. Some details: 
It is definitely tied to sunrise/dawn, as the time each day varies along with the sunrise. This makes me think it could be related to some voltage/current fluctuations that could occur at that time each day -- perhaps street lights turning off? But it does not happen EVERY day. 
 Also, a second lamp will USUALLY turn on at the same instant, but not always. Note we live in Mexico and line voltage fluctuates more than is normal in the U.S. If I turn it off immediately it will turn itself on again either immediately or within 10 - 15 seconds. This window during which this occurs is 2 - 3 minutes long.
 I hope someone can explain this, because my fallback answer is that it's haunted... 
[Edit]I'm attaching a photo that shows the lamp just after it went on at 7:20 one morning. The alarm clock is NOT connected to the lamp. The lamp is just a simple almost spherical shape. Unfortunately it does not have any model number or manufacturer information.

Comment: Are you sure it doesnt have an alarm clock? What is this lamp anyway?

Comment: Your question would be interesting if you gave a make and model for the lamp, a photo of it and the PCB, details of the type of bulb you are using and your best effort at a schematic. There is an edit link under your question ...

Comment: Here is the [edit] link.

Comment: How do you switch the lamp ON/OFF usually? How does it behave if unplugged/plugged into the wall?

Comment: Just a light touch turns it on or off. I have noticed that a voltage spike from turning a fan on or off when the lamp is off will cause a very brief slight flicker, but has never actually caused it to turn on. The lamp doesn't have a battery, will only go on when plugged into the wall socket.

Comment: It's a crappy design. Give it away. It appears to be RF noise sensitive which may be coincident with changing AC Line levels in the morning, your mobile phone  or even plug orientation sensitive or even proximity of a noisy RF clock.  It's like guessing what caused stack overflow on some random embedded product or where's Waldo.  My guess is it is supposed to sense an increase in stray line noise when you touch or get near the globe.

Comment: RF noise is something I hadn't considered -- I guess it could be that, though i wonder what could cause the RF noise at the same time (relative to sunrise) each morning.

Comment: Could a heater/air-conditioner/electric hot water heater be turning on at this time every morning?

Comment: This is normal behavior for a touch based lamp. See here for some info: https://science.howstuffworks.com/innovation/science-questions/touch-sensitive-lamp.htm

We have one and any time my dad plays with his Ham radio equipment it would regularly cycle through the three lighting levels.

Comment: Annie, thanks for the suggestions, but there isn't anything like that in our house. I'm trying to figure out what could be the cause of this electrical/RF disturbance every morning tied to the sunrise.

Comment: esilk -- thanks for the link -- very interesting. I just wish I could figure out where the RF (most likely it seems) interference is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can not comment I will post my comment as an answer.

I have a very similar sight (same?) and I have tried many things to 'fix' it. Finally one day I discovered that at the same time I pulled my back door closed (well, sort of slammed it) the light turned ON. Then the same action would also turn it Off.

I knew both the lamp and the back door light were on the same circuit. I discovered that a few of the wires in both the light switch, back door light and where the lamp where plugged in were loose. (my house is 70 years old). After tightening all of the wires my lamp has never malfunctioned again.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts -- it seems like in your case mechanical vibrations and loose wires could interact, but there are no mechanical vibrations going on in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

There's been some detailed analysis of similar problems - for example [here](http://www.arrl.org/touch-lamp)

Summary - RF energy gets into the switch IC and causes random ON/OFF.

The solution is to wire inductors or resistors in series with the touch connection to the lamp metal housing to isolate the control from a hostile EMC environment. See the link for details, but the values are around the 1k - 5kohm mark.

Note that working on such a lamp and modifying it may be hazardous if you're not familiar with mains electrical work.

Comment: thanks for the interesting link. I'm not really looking to fix the problem (it's not a big bother since it just happens once a day), I just want to understand what could possibly be the source of this that is tied to the sunrise somehow.